# Is there any consequence to using "Try Again" after failing during court?

Tags: phoenix-wright-dual-destinies

Every game in the Ace Attorney series has featured a "strikes" or "life bar" system during courtroom phases, where you receive an instant Game Over if you present incorrect evidence or make mistakes too many times. In previous games in the series, you'd have to restart from your last save after earning a Game Over in this way, but in Dual Destinies, the Game Over screen is immediately followed by a "Try Again" option, which returns you to the exact spot you were just at, and refills your life bar to maximum.

Being that it seems like this sort of negates the life bar's reason for existing in the first place, is there any consequence at all to selecting Try Again? Does it affect anything differently later on in the case/game, or does it make no difference?

Comment: You could just save right before you have to present the evidence in the predecessors. Not sure about DD however; didn't have the opportunity to buy it yet.

Comment: @Nolonar Yeah, that's what I'm used to doing in previous games, but it seems like this new option removes the need to do that. That's convenient, of course, but it makes me wonder if using "continues" in this way has any other effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, there is no penalty for using the Try Again feature**.  The likely reason that this was incorporated is because Dual Destinies expands on the Bad Ending feature present in previous games by having **several specific, detailed Game Over sequences** that can be found.  The feature is simply to facilitate the ability to easily see all of the endings in a single run.

Comment: I assumed they removed the punishment since players often save and reload before game-over inducing moments anyway.